What are my rights if an old employer claims they overpaid my pension contributions and is demanding repayment?
I was working for a company under contract from 20th September 2021 to 31st October 2022 during which time I was an employee of an umbrella company as the contract was deemed to be inside IR35. I was paid via the umbrella company who also dealt with pension contributions. I received a letter from them (see content below) on 3rd April 2024 stating that due to a software error, they had made 2 overpayments to my pension provider and they are now demanding that the overpayments are repaid.
Accordingly, I would like to understand where I stand legally on this. Ethics aside, am I legally obliged to take the action they have suggested in the letter below and instruct my pension provider to start repayment process? I was never aware that they had made overpayments to my pension provider and if I have to repay the sum, this will mean having to sell an asset class in my SIPP to cover their mistake and reduce my somewhat meger pension pot even further. Does this fall under the estoppel principle?
Any advice on this would be warmly welcomed.
LETTER CONTENT

Dear Marlon,
RE: Pension Overpayment
I am writing to inform you that during your employment with Compass CE
Ltd (on placement via recruitment agency Primis Consult Ltd) in 2022
an overpayment of £2,134.39 was made to your nominated private pension
provider, Investor SIPP Trustees Limited. This overpayment was due to
a software issue.
Specifically, two of your payments were required to reprocessed due to
changes from the agency in payroll instructions, and on both occasions
your pension contributions were incorrectly calculated by the payroll
software. This occurred on 20/9/22 and 31/10/22. The software error
has only just been discovered and reported to the provider.
I am very sorry for the inconvenience caused, but we will need the
amount of £2,134.39 to be repaid by your pension provider. Under these
circumstances, HMRC allow the repayment of a contribution made as a
result of software or administration error and there is no tax
liability resulting from this. Furthermore, if you have derived a
benefit from the overpayment, in the form of investment return, you
are able to keep that in your fund.
I attach a breakdown of all the payments made to Investor SIPP
Trustees Limited and the deductions from income resulting from your
employment. The payments total £20,472.66 and the deductions total
£18,338.27 (the difference of £2,134.39 is the overpayment).
Please could you forward this letter to your account manager at
Investor SIPP Trustees Limited so we can begin the process to put in
place the repayment.


I’m voting to close this question because it requires a professional legal advice

@mustaccio I don't disagree, but I have seen questions like this being responded and well received.

@mustaccio - I'm not looking for professional legal advice, just asking if anyone has any experience of this and if anyone can at least point me in the right direction. I posted this question here as I had found another question along similar lines:
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34471/what-are-my-rights-if-an-old-employer-claims-they-overpaid-me-and-is-demanding-r

@Marlon Pointing you in the right direction is go talk to professional legal advice like mustaccio said. When it's thousands of pounds at stake, you shouldn't listen to anyone on the internet no matter how right they sound.

If you were overpaid then you theoretically must repay that overpayment, but any interest you earned, would still be yours. The letter says as much. I don’t see why you feel slighted to be honest

I cast the finally vote to close - at face value, it seems like an honest mistake and they have pointed you to the resolution. However, this is very much a legal issue - you linked to another question - which was also closed for the same reason. We wish you the best of luck - but things like Pension Law are too niche and nuanced for us to assist with.

you conveniently leave out if you were actually overpaid.  You don't get to keep money just because someone made a mistake.  Possession is not in fact 9/10 of the law.

@TigerGuy - I mean, did the author leave that out? Their previous employer paid into a pension fund. They sent a letter to the author saying they were overpaid. The author does not claim they were NOT overpaid.  They seem frustrated that the previous employer would attempt to resolve the overpayment.

@TigerGuy, possession is 9/10ths of the law, in the sense that the law does respect the settled facts of the matter more than stale paper claims. Not only has there been maladministration of the payroll, but their admitted incompetence means they didn't discover it for 18 months. Why should we even believe that there has been an overpayment in these circumstances, rather than the payroll company imagining the mistake due to another fumble, or the payment being legitimate due to information that is now lost and forgotten?

@Steve - If the author has evidence there wasn't a payroll mistake they should bring that to the table, the fact the author did not dispute a mistake happened, makes me believe this has to do with an unsupported belief that the overpayment is actual theirs.

@Donald, his evidence presumably will be the figure on the payslip he was issued by them 18 months ago. His wages, his bank balance, and his pension balance are his. He's said he had no prior knowledge of the employer's mistake, and the payment has been settled for some time. Just because the employer has found they were making systematic errors in their procedures for the calculation of the payroll, doesn't entitle them to recover money from the employee when they've previously advised the employee years ago that he was entitled to that amount of money.

@Marlon, Before repaying anything or agreeing to the debt, which would reset the clock, do verify the statute of limitations in your jurisdiction for payroll mistakes.


Law.SE often good resource for general / hypothetically phrased questions. Your question will be closed if it asks for specific legal advice for a real situation. 2. You're in the UK: sources of free specific legal advice include Citizens Advice, ACAS and high street solicitors (free initial consultations/guidance). 3. Stephan Brancyk right to verify when this type of claim is time-barred (generally six years). 4. Ask the pension scheme what's best for you before 'ordering' them. 5. Another commenter indicates you don't have to repay an overpayment but, as a matter of law, you may have to


Top level is that if you were not supposed to get this money, you will have to return it. This has nothing to do with ethics either, it's same as if employer were to overpay you by accident - the money has to be repaid, if not it can/will be garnished from future wages instead, up for the involved parties to figure out what's best.
This is very similar, but you were overpaid through the contribution. You should speak with them, and figure how would you like to repay the money, can be some installments via cash, or speak with your pension and get them to rectify it directly. Quite sure they will be happy with either. In either case this was interest free money you got some benefit out of in your pension account.
I personally would recommend settling with repayments and cash as that's a lot less complicated than getting pensions involved, and they likely will be open to some very long payment plans as... well, going through courts for small sums is hardly worth it, especially when a voluntary settlement is easily available. But if you want to go through pension instead, mind that you won't be able to top it up this year by that amount (assuming that you are maxing your tax-free contributions already) as this won't affect this years limit. I guess you could ask for something for that if you really want to try to keep a hundred for your trouble or something like that.

"Top level is that if you were not supposed to get this money, you will have to return it." - but it's also their job to make the payroll calculations and determine the exact figures of what the OP was "supposed to get". Given the lapse of time, and if the OP was not aware of the mistake at the time of payment, then I'd be inclined to deny their request for repayment. You can't have companies thinking they can come back months or years later to argue about how they calculated your pay, when you're likely to have completely forgotten contemporary circumstances and discarded paperwork.

@Steve great, make your own answer then instead of commuting it in.

I can't make an answer - the question is closed. Moreover I'm addressing the specific points of your answer. The employer is responsible for payroll calculations (and applying the complicated legal regimes associated), not the employee, and they've advised him that he was "supposed to get" a certain level of pension contribution. You wouldn't accept a lawyer saying "you know that final settlement I advised you on 18 months ago? I'm afraid you're actually liable for another £2k because it wasn't supposed to be what I told you it was". Why would you accept an employer saying so?

Because of the law. Also, yes, you would have to accept that from a lawyer if the fineprint is good - otherwise there would be a liability insurance case against the lawyer. Miscalculations happen and errors generally are corrected.

This is bad advice. Before repaying anything, which would reset the clock, the OP should verify the statute of limitations for payroll mistakes not caused by him.

Settling the payment in cash instead of having it restituted through the pension program might not be a good idea for tax reasons. I don't know about the UK, but in NL there are maximum percentages of your income that can be put into your pension income-tax-free, and above that it would be taxable, so if there was an overpayment, you could be liable for additional tax if you pay it back yourself instead of having the pension program transfer it back to the employer.

@MarkRotteveel that only applies if you are going over contributions, judging by the sums OP says, I don't think they are anywhere near those (and if they were, that would've been billed 2 years ago when overpayment happened, or at worst last year when year end taxes are done).

At two places I received a generous settlement, with the stipulation that if I sued the company, I would only receive the legally required settlement (less than half of what I received) and would have to repay the rest. You should read the contract very, very carefully and there's at least a possibility that the company cannot sue you either because such a clause could apply to both sides.  In that case it would be a very valuable learning experience for them. And if you received £2,000 more than you should, what are the chances that someone else received £2,000 less?
